# AWK, printf format specifier %x has problems with negative values

Tags: awk, printf

It seems AWK has problems with the unsigned hex format specifier:

```
echo 0x80000000 | awk '{printf("0x%08x\n", $1)}'
```

gives back: `0x7fffffff`

Is this a known problem with awk?

Thanks!

Comment: @roe: thanks for your response! the version is not known, as it is a part of BusyBox, and for that reason it doesn't report its version. But on Xubuntu, I've seen a similar behaviour with version GNU AWK 3.1.6, the response wasn't 0x8000000 but 0x00000000

Comment: the 0x000000 response is because it doesn't accept hexadecimal input, so the numeric value is zero. 0x8 as input will still yield 0x00000000

Comment: @roe, then the following should work:
echo 0x80000000 | awk '{printf("0x%08x\n", strtonum($1))}'

gives back

0x80000000. Thanks for pointing out that! Things don't usually do that what you expect of them to do!

as expected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that awk only converts input parameters to numbers automatically if they are decimal. But this should work:

echo 0x80000000 | awk '{printf("0x%08x\n", strtonum($1))}'

It's all explained in here, in the strtonum section:
http://www.gnu.org/manual/gawk/html_node/String-Functions.html#String-Functions

Comment: For `gawk` you can use the `--non-decimal-data` option.

Answer (score 0):

Not seeing it here, although I wasn't able to use the hex input as you are, but converted to decimal was no problem.

```
$ echo 2147483648 | awk '{printf("0x%08x\n", $1)}'
0x80000000
```

If you care to enlighten us what platform you're on (this was GNU awk 3.1.5), we might be able to help you more.